# changing content in table according to dropdown selection

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, angularjs

I want to change to content in a table after user selecting value from dropdown list. there are two dropdowns - one to select user and second to select script. i want that when user chooses a user the table will show only rows with the chosen user and same for script.
this is my dropdown:

```
     include_once "dbConnect.php";
    $query = "SELECT user_id FROM users";
    $result = mysql_query($query); ?>
    <select name="select1">
    <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $line['user_id'];?>">
    <?php echo $line['user_id'];?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>

    <?php
     include_once "dbConnect.php";
    $query = "SELECT script_name FROM scripts";
    $result = mysql_query($query); ?>
    <select name="select1">
    <?php while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $line['script_name'];?>">
    <?php echo $line['script_name'];?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

thats the data in the table:

```
$json_response = array();

$results= mysql_query("select user_id,script_name,cron_format from users,scripts");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($results, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
   array_push($json_response,$row);
}
echo json_encode($json_response);
```

and this is the table:

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead>
            <td>user name</td>
            <td>script name</td>
            <td>cron format</td>
            <td>schedule last update</td>
            <td>next execution time</td>
            <td>script exec</td>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
                <td>{{x.user_id}}</td>
                <td>{{x.script_name}}</td>
                <td><span class="editme" contenteditable="true">{{x.cron_format}}</span></td>
                <td>{{x.schedule_last_update}}</td>
                <td>{{x.next_execution_time}}</td>
                <td>{{x.script_exec}}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

at the beginning table shows all users and for each user all scripts. 
any solution is great but angularJs one will be great++...thanks

Comment: can we see the resultant `html` for the select boxes?

Comment: its in between the first peace of code

Comment: no, I mean the actual `html` that is generated by the php

Comment: two dropdown : one with :1,2,3,4,5 for user id's and the other: script_one,script_two...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below `jQuery` solution should work for you. Just give `class='filterElements'` to any select element that you want to be able to filter the table. The `data-cell-to-filter="c0"` property on the element will determine which cell the element will filter by.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#table').filterRowsByValue( $('.filterElements') );
  // $('.filterElements').change(); // uncomment to start with blank table
});  


jQuery.fn.filterRowsByValue = function(masterSelects) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var table = this;
    var rows = [];
    $(table).find('tr').each(function() {
        var cells={};
        $(this).find('td').each (function(i, e) {
           cells['c'+i] = $(this).html();
        });    
      rows.push(cells);
    });
    $(table).data('tr', rows);
    
    masterSelects.bind('change', function() {
      var cur=this;
      masterSelects.each(function(i,e){
        if( e != cur ){
          $(e).val("0");
         }
      });
      var rows = $(table).empty().scrollTop(0).data('tr');
      
      var search = '^'+$.trim($(this).val())+'$';
      var regex = new RegExp(search,'gi');
      var cel = $(this).data( "cell-to-filter" ); 
      $.each(rows, function(i,e) {
        var row = rows[i];
        if(row[cel].match(regex) !== null) {
          var cellArr=[];
          for (var curCell in row) {
              if(row.hasOwnProperty(cel)){
               cellArr.push('<td>'+row[curCell]+'</td>');
              }
          }
         $(table).append( '<tr>'+cellArr.join('')+'</tr>' );
        }
      });
    });
    
  });
};
```

```css
.table-bordered, .table-bordered td{
 
 border: thin solid #575656;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="selection">
<select name='user' class='filterElements' data-cell-to-filter="c0">
 <option value = '0'>(Select user)</option> 
 <option value = '1'>1</option>
 <option value = '2'>2</option>
 <option value = '3'>3</option>
 <option value = '4'>4</option>
 <option value = '5'>5</option>
</select>

<select name='scripts' class='filterElements' data-cell-to-filter="c1">
 <option value = '0'>(Select script)</option> 
 <option value='script_one'>script_one</option>
 <option value='script_two'>script_two</option>
 <option value='script_three'>script_three</option>
 <option value='script_four'>script_foure</option>
 <option value='script_five'>script_five</option>
</select>  
</div>


<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
  <td>user name</td>
    <td>script name</td>
    <td>cron format</td>
    <td>schedule last update</td>
    <td>next execution time</td>
    <td>script exec</td>
      </thead>
  <tbody  id="table" >
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>script_five</td>
      <td><span class="editme"three lass="editme" contenteditable="true">Some stuff</span></td>
      <td>7/11/14</td>
      <td>15:00</td>
      <td>Some stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>script_three</td>
      <td><span class="editme" contenteditable="true">Some stuff</span></td>
      <td>7/11/14</td>
      <td>15:00</td>
      <td>Some stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>script_one</td>
      <td><span class="editme" contenteditable="true">Some stuff</span></td>
      <td>7/11/14</td>
      <td>15:00</td>
      <td>Some stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
      <td>3</td>
      <td>script_five</td>
      <td><span class="editme" contenteditable="true">Some stuff</span></td>
      <td>7/11/14</td>
      <td>15:00</td>
      <td>Some stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>script_two</td>
      <td><span class="editme" contenteditable="true">Some stuff</span></td>
      <td>7/11/14</td>
      <td>15:00</td>
      <td>Some stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
      <td>2</td>
      <td>script_two</td>
      <td><span class="editme" contenteditable="true">Some stuff</span></td>
      <td>7/11/14</td>
      <td>15:00</td>
      <td>Some stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>script_five</td>
      <td><span class="editme" contenteditable="true">Some stuff</span></td>
      <td>7/11/14</td>
      <td>15:00</td>
      <td>Some stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
      <td>5</td>
      <td>script_one</td>
      <td><span class="editme" contenteditable="true">Some stuff</span></td>
      <td>7/11/14</td>
      <td>15:00</td>
      <td>Some stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
      <td>4</td>
      <td>script_five</td>
      <td><span class="editme" contenteditable="true">Some stuff</span></td>
      <td>7/11/14</td>
      <td>15:00</td>
      <td>Some stuff</td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in data">
      <td>1</td>
      <td>script_four</td>
      <td><span class="editme" contenteditable="true">Some stuff</span></td>
      <td>7/11/14</td>
      <td>15:00</td>
      <td>Some stuff</td>
    </tr>
    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: any option to add pagination?

Comment: @user7441072 sure, you could count the number of filtered rows and hide all of them over a set number (like say 50) then provide buttons to move forward and backward through the dataset. That said, if you need filtering and pagination, I'd just use [datatables](https://datatables.net/)